# RandomOverSampler conditions to create equal distribution

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, imblearn

I am currently working on an ML based project and there is a slight imbalance in my data and would require an over_sampling technique. The features (X_train) dimension is (90664, 190) and target (Y_binary_train_trans) is (90664, ). However, the code runs and still outputs the same, unequal distribution of the target. 
Here is the code used for RandomOverSampler, it has been tried using smote as well;

```
counter= Counter(Y_binary_train_trans)
ros= RandomOverSampler(random_state=42)
X_train, Y_binary_train_trans = ros.fit_resample(X_train,Y_binary_train_trans)
counter = Counter(Y_binary_test_trans)
```

Comment: I'm unable to replicate those results. Could you provide Minimal and reproducible example? [This](https://git.io/Jfe7m) code is build from your problem's description and it works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

```
counter= Counter(Y_binary_train_trans)
ros= RandomOverSampler(random_state=42)
X_train, Y_binary_train_trans = ros.fit_resample(X_train,Y_binary_train_trans)
counter = Counter(Y_binary_test_trans)
```

As for this code, your second counter counts the test samples and not the training samples which you actually changed!

Instead it should be:

```
counter= Counter(Y_binary_train_trans)
ros= RandomOverSampler(random_state=42)
X_train, Y_binary_train_trans = ros.fit_resample(X_train,Y_binary_train_trans)
counter = Counter(Y_binary_train_trans)
```